# List all records and count how many times they are used in a date range in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a list of 158 unique items in a table. I am attempting to how many times these items are shipped to customers within a certain date range. I need to list all 158 items when I run the query. If it has not shipped within that time period I want a 0 for the count. What I have so far just wont list the item if it is not in that date range. I'm sure this is disgustingly easy and I'm just over thinking it.

```
 select Applicator
, count(fshipdate) as 'Times Used'
,sum(fqty_iss) as 'Terminal count'
from HowOftenUsed
where Applicator <> ''
and fshipdate between '01/01/2016' and '05/16/2016'
group by Applicator
```

Comment: [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server] are competing RDBMS products from different vendors: the former, a free open-source cross-platform product now owned by the Oracle Corporation; the latter, a commercial closed-source Windows-only product from Microsoft.  Why is this question tagged with both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for all DB engines

```
select Applicator,
       count(case when fshipdate not between '01/01/2016' and '05/16/2016' 
                  then null 
                  else fshipdate 
             end) as 'Times Used',
       sum(case when fshipdate not between '01/01/2016' and '05/16/2016' 
                then null 
                else fqty_iss 
           end) as 'Terminal count'
from HowOftenUsed
where Applicator <> ''
group by Applicator
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the list 158 unique items in your table and make a `Left Outer Join` with the `distinct` list

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT applicator 
         FROM   howoftenused) 
SELECT C.applicator, 
       Count(fshipdate) AS 'Times Used', 
       Sum(fqty_iss)    AS 'Terminal count' 
FROM   cte C 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN howoftenused H 
                    ON C.applicator = H.applicator 
                       AND fshipdate BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '05/16/2016' 
WHERE  C.applicator <> '' 
GROUP  BY C.applicator
```